# When AV software puts files and various malicious "objects" in "quarantine", what exactly do they actually do?

Tags: windows, security, malware, anti-virus, malwarebytes

I had malware on a computer, which Malwarebytes managed to remove. Or did it? It rather "put it in quarantine". And it's remained like that. I see no way to actually delete it.

This appears to not be unique to Malwarebytes at all. It seems to be a standard, established practice in AV software since many years.

But what does this mean? Why not actually delete the malicious files? Why keep them on the system, even if in "quarantine"?

Answer (score 1):

> Why not actually delete the malicious files? Why keep them on the
> system, even if in "quarantine"?

All AV Apps make mistakes (both ways).

Files are put in Quarantine so that the user of the computer can review, delete if truly malware, or whitelist and release if not malware.

This is a very standard approach to malware review.

If the virus is a very serious threat, it will be deleted. I have seen this as well.

See if this Malwarebytes article helps you.

To choose items you want to keep or remove, follow these instructions:

```
Open Malwarebytes for Windows.
Click the Detection History card.
In the Quarantined items tab, check the boxes of the items you want to restore or delete.
Click the Restore or Delete button. Deleting the items permanently removes them from your device.
```

[MW Bytes](https://support.malwarebytes.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038479214-Restore-or-delete-quarantined-items-in-Malwarebytes-for-Windows)